# The custom tag for the registration form is used for the checkout page. How to avoid it

Tags: forms, tags, shopify, liquid

I want to add a tag that will be automatically added for new registered users.

On the registration page, I added the following code to the registration form

```
{%- if request.page_type contains '/register' -%}
  <input type="hidden" name="customer[tags]" value="registered_user">
{%- endif -%}
```

but it also adds this tag to the checkout form for customers that do not have accounts.
Do you have any idea how this can be fixed? Thanks

Comment: What is the difference between a customer registering outside checkout and one registering inside checkout?

Comment: Customers can make a purchase as a guest (without creating an account), or they can create an account and, for example, subscribe to the newsletter (or not subscribe). 
In all these cases, Shopify assigns the same tag to all customers, and I would like different tags to be assigned to them, allowing me to segment them into different lists

Comment: You did not explain why you would segment a customer signing up before checkout or during. As you know, even an anon customer gets an account, so it is the same. They are registered.

Comment: If you wanted to reward a customer registered before purchasing anything, you could use a Proxy call to an App that provides the logged in customer ID. Since they are logged in, you can check if they have previous purchases. If not, tag them as special. Any customers registered anon via checkout would not have that tag, hence, your list is now segmented.